# Multiple WCF services under one .net Project?

Tags: .net, wcf, iis

Instead of having 1 wcf project for each wcf service I am planning to have, I want to have only 1 Project in visual studio and different wcf services in different folders.

the wcf services are iis hosted by the way.

When deployed, I'd like to keep the same structure in iis, which means under only one iis virtual directory separed by folders inside of it but with the wcf respecting its's own configuration (each wcf service with its own .config file )

Is this allowed? Am I stuck having 1 wcf project per wcf service? am I stuck with 1 iis site for each wcf service?

please help

Comment: Yes, but in my experience is only possible with copy and paste the first svc file and change the names references, the content class svc.cs file and create the service and enpoint tags in web.config file. If you add a new WCF service from wizard, the web.cofig is changed and the services have this error: "[InvalidOperationException: Type 'MyService.Service1' couldn't be found"

Answer (score -1):

You can of course have multiple WCF services per project. There is no need to separate them into folders but you can do that.

I don't know if WCF supports nested .config files. In any case you can put all the config settings into the web.config. Ideally, the services would share a lot of configuration anyway.